# Joomla 2.5... Virtuemart 2. Your Virtuemart installation contains an error:

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Your Virtuemart installation contains an error: No user as marked as vendor. Please fix this in your phpMyAdmin and

```
set #__virtuemart_vmusers.user_is_vendor = 1 and #__virtuemart_vmusers.virtuemart_vendor_id =1
```

to one of your administrator users. Please update all users to be associated with virtuemart_vendor_id 1.

Please help me to solv this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the table `_virtuemart_vmusers` . Inside it, you'll see one data exist. Go ahead and  'Edit' the row

`virtuemart_user_id` : (depending on your Joomla Admin ID. In my case, the ID is **116**)
`virtuemart_vendor_id`: (since my Joomla Admin ID is **116**, here put **116**)
user_is_vendor: key in '**1**'

See image for details
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is now a way to do this from the front-end as well.

In the Joomla back-end,

1. Navigate to Virtuemart > Tools > Tools & Migration > Migration
2. Update the Joomla Admin ID in the "Write here the new store owner id" text field and click on the "Set Store Owner" Button
3. DONE!